# it is possible to use ( as a regular expression in c++?

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to get names and passwords (it's an exercise, nothing bad: p) of a big document.

I am using regular expressions for names, as follows

```
regex e ("\\ b (name) ([^] *)");
```

The problem comes with the keys, since they come right after a ( and if I do `regex p ("\\ b (() ([^] *)")`, it gives me an error in the memory where it is initializing , it may not be initializing well, but I do not find anything about this with respect to specific characters like (

fo example DOC:

name Turing
pass (31)               <--  I cant take this 31

Regards!

Comment: In a regexp you have to escape all chars that have a special meaning using a backslash. ```\```, and `(` marks the beginning of a group.

Comment: To add up to @t.niese's comment remind that backslashes in c++ string literals must be escaped as well (but seems you already know that).

Comment: hi thanks for answer @t.niese and i use it, but can you put me a example??

Comment: You may want to use raw string literals for this. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/raw-string-literal-c/

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out in comments, you need to escape brackets if you want to match against them. Note, however, that then there are two escaping mechanisms: That of the regex engine, and that of C++ string literals.

So for example, the regex engine might expect something like this:

```
\(name\) \(\d+\)
```

Here the brackets `()` are escaped, so that the regex engine will not not use them for grouping. Thus the above regex matches, for instance, against `(name) (123)`.

Now to write a C++ string literal, you need to escape (in particular) the backslashes. Thus you'd write

```
std::regex e("\\(name\\) \\(\\d+\\)");
```

If you want to avoid these nasty `\\`, you may also use a *raw string literal*:

```
std::regex e(R"X(\(name\) \(\d+\))X");
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here the prefixed "R" indicates that you write a raw string literal. The `X(` and `)X` are arbitrary *delimiters*. (More on this on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal or various SO questions.)

---

By the way, keep an eye on the spaces in your regex. You wrote `[^] *`, which matches one arbitrary character followed by any amount of spaces. This is probably not what you meant.